# Как сделать чтобы Random не повторялся

Tags: java, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

```
TextView resText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
r = new Random();
output = r.nextInt(5) +1;//если 0   +1
resText2.setText("" + output);
```

---

Не работает

```
 Set<Integer> existing = new HashSet();

        public  void  onClick_Start(View view) {

            TextView resText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            r = new Random();
            output = r.nextInt(5) +1;//если 0   +1


            do {
                output = r.nextInt(5) +1;
            } while(existing.contains(output));
            existing.add(output);
            resText2.setText("" + output);
        }
```

Comment: Я новичок если ошибусь то ничего) Попробуйте цикл for(int i = 0; i<1; i++);
И все)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно так

```
Set<Integer> existing = new HashSet(); // где-нибудь за пределами метода
```

---

```
do {
    output = r.nextInt(5) +1;
} while(existing.contains(output));
```

Comment: все равно .....

Comment: После цикла надо добавить новое число к старым `existing.add(output);`